# I am trying to generate a https certificate from openssl but getting error

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate

When i am trying to generate an https certificate for my express app using below command i am getting error

`openssl req -new -key privateKey.pem -out request.pem`

Can't open C:/OpenSSL/SSL/openssl.cnf for reading, No such file or directory
1332:error:02001003:system library:fopen:No such process:crypto/bio/bss_file.c:69:fopen('C:/OpenSSL/SSL/openssl.cnf','r')

Answer (score 1):

First i had set the environment varaiable for openssl.conf

set OPENSSL_CONF=c:/program%20files/openssl/openssl.cnf // or what erver the location for openssl.conf

Then run gain the command,

openssl req -new -key privateKey.pem -out request.pem

// keep in mind i already generated the
// private key using command `openssl genrsa -out privateKey.pem 1024`

It asks for a couple of quesitions and then generate the certificate at the folder location.